# Ruby on Rails 2 SyntaxError for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This form in Ruby on Rails 2 gives an error:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

The error is  `SyntaxError in Session`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do

```
<% form_for(:session, :url => session_path) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

First, in Rails 2.x you use `<%` instead of `<%=` when you pass block to method called inside. Second, I used "rocket style hash" here so it works in `Ruby 1.8.7`.

Answer (score 1):

in ruby 1.8 style of hash was like this `{:key => value}`, in ruby 1.9 we can also use this syntaxe or use the new style like `key: value`

switch your ruby version which you use with rails 2 you check if do you should take the first or the second style

Comment: It doesn't depend on Rails version. It depends on Ruby version. This "new" syntax was introduced in `Ruby 1.9`.

Comment: thank for note, i just say rails because i think if he use rails 2 , probability that he use ruby 1.8 is heigher. i update my answer thank's

Comment: You're right. Probability is much higher. Now your answer is correct and is supplementar to mine, so I give you upvote. :)